# Passing SSH password automatically to SSH session in PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, shell

I am trying to pass SSH password automatically to local Hyper-V VM
i have SSH installed in PowerShell but I didn't find the proper command to use in order to send the password.
because it is for work project - I am not allowed (security issues) to install additional applications.
the computer does include Mobaxterm (don't know if it helpful)

currently I tried the following commands but didn't succeeded:

```
$Password = `your text`
$User = `your text`
$ComputerName = `your text`
$Command = `your text`

$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force
$Credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($User, $secpasswd)

ssh.exe -ComputerName $ComputerName -Credential $Credentials #Connect Over SSH
```

Comment: ssh is sending a command line and you must terminate with a return.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using EOF?

```
ssh $URL <<EOF
$PASSWORD
EOF
```